# How to mock window.navigator.language using jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am trying to mock the `window.navigator.language` attribute in the browser in my jest unit tests so I can test that the content on my page is using the correct language

I have found people online using this:

`Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'language', {value: 'es', configurable: true});`

I have set it right at the top of my test file and it is working there

however, when I redefine in an individual test (and people set to make sure configurable was set to true) it wont redefine it and is just using the old value, does anyone know a way to definitely change it?

```
beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
    Object.defineProperty(global.navigator, 'language', {value: 'es', configurable: true});
    wrapper = shallow(<Component {...props} />)
})

  it('should do thing 1', () => {
      Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'language', {value: 'de', configurable: true});
      expect(wrapper.state('currentLanguage')).toEqual('de')
    })

it('should do thing 2', () => {
  Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'language', {value: 'pt', configurable: true});
  expect(wrapper.state('currentLanguage')).toEqual('pt')
})
```

for these tests it is not changing the language to the new language I have set, always using the one at the top

Comment: Please, don't describe what you're doing but provide actual code . https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is necessary for code questions.

Comment: wasn't global.navigator that you could access and mock it? (maybe my memory fails)

Comment: @estus have made changes

Comment: What is `Component`?

Comment: the component I'm mocking out. it doesn't hugely matter does it? as I'm more concerned that the object define thing is not resetting my property. once that is working i can fix the rest

Comment: Of course, it matters because it's unclear how it uses window.navigator.language. *I'm more concerned that the object define thing is not resetting my property* - there's no evidence that the property isn't resetted. From the code you posted it's only clear that the component doesn't take changed property into account, possibly because tests were written the wrong way.

Comment: I am logging the window.nav.lan property in component and it is not coming through with a different value for each test

Comment: I know what to do with property in component, I just need it coming through correctly which it is not for now and I cant work out why

Comment: if i told you `<Component />` just logged out the property then can you tell me why it's still not correct

Comment: *just logged out the property* - at which point? Constructor? componentDidMount? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is required by SO rules because it allows to just understand the problem by reading the question and skip long negotiations on what should be posted and what should not.

Comment: ok yeh it's in componentdidmount, basically in here I log the window.navigator.language and it is only giving me the value from the first Object.defineproperty at the top of the test file. it's not changing it for individual tests, it's nothing to do with the code as I've stripped it all down. for some reason jest is not resetting the property to be a different value every time :/

Comment: *for some reason jest is not resetting the property to be a different value every time* - there are no evidences that this is true because you don't assert `window.navigator.location`, only its expected side effects, and the expectations were wrong. I provided the answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

[`window.navigator` and its properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) are read-only, this is the reason why `Object.defineProperty` is needed to set `window.navigator.language`. It's supposed to work for changing property value multiple times.

The problem is that the component is already instantiated in `beforeEach`, `window.navigator.language` changes don't affect it.

Using `Object.defineProperty` for mocking properties manually will require to store original descriptor and restore it manually as well. This can be done with `jest.spyOn`. `jest.clearAllMocks()` wouldn't help for manual spies/mocks, it may be unneeded for Jest spies.

It likely should be:

```
let languageGetter;

beforeEach(() => {
  languageGetter = jest.spyOn(window.navigator, 'language', 'get')
})

it('should do thing 1', () => {
  languageGetter.mockReturnValue('de')
  wrapper = shallow(<Component {...props} />)
  expect(wrapper.state('currentLanguage')).toEqual('de')
})
...
```

Comment: `language property does not exist` Ive tried changing window to global as well

Comment: This depends on your setup. Changing to global can't help because `navigator` is browser feature. It should exists if Jest was configured to use JSDOM. Make sure that you did that. But I'm not sure how you previous attempt could work because there would be no `window.navigator` without JSDOM. Make sure your dependencies are up to date. I just successfully tested it with jest@23 and jsdom@11.

Comment: I thought we use global because jest has no concept of a window?

Comment: Jest doesn't. JSDOM does. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string . `window` is actually `global.window`.

Comment: what about that?

Comment: I see no contradictions. JSDOM polyfills browser-specific globals. It's assigned as `global` properties` by Jest. Yes, `global.window === global` in this case. This is true only if Jest was configured to use JSDOM.

Comment: ok regardless, I can't see why it's not working :(. the only differences is im on jest 22.4 and im rendering wrapper = shallow in the beforeeach rather than the test. other than that. exactly the same and i cant see how either of those would fix undefined :(

Comment: ok upgrading jest did fix that. but now it's just coming through as `en-US` all the time

Comment: *rendering wrapper = shallow in the beforeeach rather than the test* - there shouldn't be such differences. The answer contains the code that should work. That you do `shallow` in `beforeEach` is the exact reason why you have this problem, *The problem is that the component is already instantiated in beforeEach, window.navigator.language changes don't affect it*.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a little bit to Estus Flask's answer, you can also spy on your setup file:

In jest config file activate the setupFiles feature:

`setupFiles: ['./test/mock-data/globals.js']`

Then inside globals.js spy on the userAgent or any other property:

`global.userAgent = jest.spyOn(navigator, 'userAgent', 'get');`

Finally in your test mock the return value:

```
describe('abc', () => {
  global.userAgent.mockReturnValue(
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4)\
           AppleWebKit/600.1.2 (KHTML, like Gecko)\
           Version/13.0.0 Safari/600.1.2'
  );
  test('123', async () => {
    const result = await fnThatCallsOrUseTheUserAgent();
    expect(result).toEqual('Something');
  });
});
```

Comment: This produces an error for me "userAgent is not declared configurable"

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively

jest config file

```
setupFiles: ['./test/mock-data/globals.js']
```

globals.js

```
const navigator = { language: 'Chalcatongo Mixtec', ...anyOtherPropertiesYouNeed };

Object.defineProperty(window, 'navigator', {
   value: navigator,
   writable: true
});
```

then you can mutate freely in your individual test setup

Comment: this leaks onto other tests I believe, you'd need an `after` to put it back to what it was before.

Comment: It messed up my `navigator` property, but thanks for the `setupFiles` part.  In my case, this worked: `Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'language', {
  value: 'pt-BR',
  writable: true,
})
`