# Jest: Mocking navigator.storage.persist

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs, storage, navigator

I am trying to mock the response for `navigator.storage.persist`:

```
 test('Navigator.storage.persist error should be caught', async () => {
        const persistMock = jest.fn(() => Promise.reject('Persist error'));

        Object.defineProperty(global.navigator,
            { 'storage': 'persist' }, {
            value: persistMock,
            configurable: true
        });

        try {
            await doStuff();
            expect(global.navigator.storage.persist.mock.calls).to.equal(1);
            expect(axios.mock.calls).to.equal(1);
        } catch (error) {
            expect(error).toBeUndefined();
        }
    })
```

The error I get: `ReferenceError: persist is not defined`

```
//Original Code

//Code in doStuff()
...
 try {
        const granted = await navigator.storage.persist();
        if (granted)
            console.log("Storage is now going to be persistent...", granted);
    } catch (error) {
        errorMessage = `Client did not allow storage to be persistent..${error}`;
    }
...
```

I know I'm mocking it wrong, but I cannot find any existing examples on web to imitate.
At most I've seen something like [How to mock window.navigator.language using jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52868727/how-to-mock-window-navigator-language-using-jest) ,
but in my case `persist` is nested in navigator.storage and I'm not sure how to get to that layer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Here is the unit test solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
export async function doStuff() {
  try {
    const granted = await navigator.storage.persist();
    if (granted) {
      console.log('Storage is now going to be persistent...', granted);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    const errorMessage = `Client did not allow storage to be persistent..${error.message}`;
    throw new Error(errorMessage);
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { doStuff } from './';

describe('61069460', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  it('should granted', async () => {
    const persistMock = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(true);
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'storage', {
      value: {
        persist: persistMock,
      },
      configurable: true,
    });
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    await doStuff();
    expect(persistMock).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('Storage is now going to be persistent...', true);
  });

  it('should throw custom error', async () => {
    const mError = new Error('IO');
    const persistMock = jest.fn().mockRejectedValueOnce(mError);
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'storage', {
      value: {
        persist: persistMock,
      },
      configurable: true,
    });
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    await expect(doStuff()).rejects.toThrowError('Client did not allow storage to be persistent..IO');
    expect(persistMock).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(logSpy).not.toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61069460/index.test.ts (9.134s)
  61069460
    ✓ should granted (15ms)
    ✓ should throw custom error (3ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866
    Storage is now going to be persistent... true

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 4                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.135s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/61069460

Comment: Thank you so much for the very detailed answer!! Your answer is very clear and makes a lot of sense; however, I'm having trouble to reproduce it. On further looking at my code, I have ```if(navigator.storage && navigator.storage.persist) await doStuff()```. It seems like in the test suite, it does not recognize navigator.storage. Should I have declared the mock elsewhere? Many, many thanks!